# Как правильно вывести элементы кортежа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток.

```
for items in sheet['B%s' %(counter):'D%s' %(counter)]:
         for iitems in items:
                 toreturn = iitems.value
```

Где iitems.value = такой кортеж:

```
Text1
12345
Text3
```

Нужно вывести каждый элемент кортежа в отдельную переменную.
Банальное iitems.value[0] выводит только первую букву первого слова в кортеже.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

По совету пробовал такой способ, но int значение мешает ('int' object has no attribute 'splitlines')

```
for iitems in items:
    for line in iitems.value.splitlines():
        print(line)
```

P.S. Если перевести в список - получается ['T','e','x','t','1'] что мягко говоря не подходит тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val1 = '''Text1
12345
Text3'''
a, b, c, *d = tpl = tuple(val1.split())
print(tpl)
print(a, b, c, d)

val2 = 'Text1', 12345, 'Text3', 123, 321
a, b, c, *d = val2
print(a, b, c, d)
```

out:

```
('Text1', '12345', 'Text3')
Text1 12345 Text3 []
Text1 12345 Text3 [123, 321]
```

Comment: Сделал все как написано - как только доходит до интового значения - сразу 'int' object has no attribute 'split'. Беда прямо какая-то.

Comment: приведите реальный пример, тип данных, распаковываемых из tupple  элементов, не имеет значения для распаковки